# ASP.Net - Unable to access Downloads folder from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

This relates to my previous post.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937117/c-sharp-unbale-to-access-
downloads-folder?noredirect=1#comment78832001_45937117
```

What I want is to access "Downloads" folder from an ASP.Net web application.

```
  string pathUser = 
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
 string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
 string commentImagePath =pathDownload +"\\test.png";
```

Then I realized that the above code works in a Desktop application.
That is the UserProfile is available in that "Environment", but not in the web application's environment.

I have some download happening, and the content will be downloaded to the "Downloads" folder.
That is why I need the "Downloads" folder . I need to access that content.
Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't "reach out" of a web application into a users local machine. Think for a second, what security implications that would have if it were possible?!

Comment: You cannot access user's local folder, you can access only server's folders, due to security and hosting asp apps. If you are posing any downloadable file you dont need to access the Downloads folder, otherwise you're writing malware

Comment: Actually you **can** do that, but what is the reason to not use site's local folders?

Answer (score 0):

Think that the Downloads folder is different for each user in the system , so you'll get c:\users\usera\downloads and c:\users\userb\downloads. So when you mean Downloads, you actually mean a different physical path.

At the same time, your ASP .NET application, if hosted in IIS will impersonate a specific user, so make sure that user has enough privileges to the path of interest. Also consider that the Downloads folder might be a folder that Windows will protect by default from being accessed across accounts.

I think you'd be better off saving files to a specific folder relative to your root of the website. Otherwise try to map specific folders from your drive as a Virtual Directory in IIS so the site would see it as relative to root, whilst in reality it lives somewhere else.